# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: id_blake2s256 while using bouncycastle

Tags: bouncycastle

I am trying to write an app which stores the user data in one App Engine environment, which generates a unique JWT token and the same token is used in other App Engine environments to validate the user. Simple enough, right ?

Now the JWTToken gets created (and I am able to decode is locally on my env as well as I have the keys to decrypt it). However, on the app engine, it throws up an weird exception as shown below. Note that all the jars have been added to the Eclipse app engine project. Also, the other app engine project which also uses the same APIs to generate the token, appears to work fine. Any clues will be of immense help.

The code fails on the following line:
java.security.Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider())

Exception is as follows (I could not add the complete stacktrace as it has references to our code which cannot be exposed)

java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: id_blake2s256
    at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-e3210445ee703a77(Request.java)
    at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.digest.Blake2s$Mappings.configure(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider.loadAlgorithms(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider.setup(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:32)
    at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider.(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 1):

Was able to fix this problem by following this procedure (it took me about 4 hours to finally arrive at this solution):
1. Exclude ALL the jar files
2. Include the jar files back one by one
3. Finally add the bouncycastle jar files back

To answer v6ak's post, the application was indeed working before, for some reason all hell broke loose when I tried to push a new piece of code to my GAE env, although the local environment continued to work without a hitch.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are using the same libraries in runtime as those you are using for compilation? It looks like you have a different version of BouncyCastle.

First, I know a little about your deployment. But double check if you use the same library versions during compilation and run is a good first step.

Second, I check if the BouncyCastle is present in the GAE environment. There were some such cases, like on Android, where SpongyCastle (a renamed version of BouncyCastle) needs to be used: https://rtyley.github.io/spongycastle/